# Mapping sphere surface to a vector space such that distances are preserved?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

I have a unit radius sphere (say in 3D) centered on the origin. Thus the shortest distance between two points on the sphere is the geodesic. Is there a transformation (linear or non-linear) on the points on the sphere to a higher-dimensional space (or lower if it exists), such that the distance between the points on the sphere is preserved in the transformed space as well.

To make it more rigorous: let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the two points on the sphere. Let $y_1=T(x_1)$ and $y_2=T(x_2)$ be the transformed points. Let $d_s(x_1,x_2)$ be the shortest distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ on the sphere's surface. Is there any T(.) such that $$d_s(x_1,x_2)=||y_1-y_2||_2^2$$ (the Euclidean distance) in the transformed space holds.

Any reference to relevant research or literature is welcome as well. Any engineering approaches are welcome too.

Comment: Do you want it to hold for all $x_1, x_2$ in the sphere?

Comment: Ideally Yes. Approximation for T(.) is fine as well.

Answer (score 10):

When $d=1$ it is of course possible to embed large chunks of $S^d$  isometrically in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

When $d\geq2$ it is not possible to embed even tiny pieces of $S^d$  isometrically in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

*Proof.* Take any three points $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3\in S^d$ forming a small equilateral triangle in the metric of $S^d$. This then is an "ordinary" spherical triangle $\triangle$  with side length $s>0$ on the $2$-sphere $S^d\cap\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle$. A map $f$ of the required kind will map the $x_i$ to the vertices $y_i$ of an equilateral triangle $\triangle'$ embedded in ${\mathbb R}^n$, and having side length $s$ as well. The distance from a vertex $y_i$ to the midpoint of the opposite side in $\triangle'$ amounts to ${\sqrt{3}\over2}s$, which is certainly different from the corresponding distance in $\triangle$.

Comment: it is an honour to meet you Prof: Blatter. This is an engineering problem wherein the sphere is the surface of earth. I have lattitudes and longitudes of different points on the surface. We want to convert this to some space such that the distance is approximately preserved.

Comment: Cartographers of six centuries have come up with several proposals to attack this problem. It's called map projection; see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

Comment: @AritraGhosh my post links to the projection that seems most appropriate for your goals. It maps the geodesic between two points to a straight line between those two points, preserving the shortest distance.

Comment: @Bey Yes, it seems like addressing my problem. I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I will take a look at your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Gnomonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection) projection to $\mathbb{R}^2$ would do the trick.

It maps great circles (i.e. Geodesics) on a sphere to straight lines on a plane. Therefore the shortest path is preserved.

Comment: It's true that gnomonic projection maps great circles to Euclidean lines, but spherical distances are not approximately preserved in the image, which seems contrary to the OP's aims. As the page itself notes, "No distortion occurs at the tangent point, but distortion increases rapidly away from it."

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yea...it's not perfect but as Christian points out its not possible in a universal way. This at least maps shortest paths to shortest paths...but the metric value is not preserved.